# How to count the number of repeated values between separation values from one column and store that value in an other table

Tags: mysql

I have a table (cor) with two columns (id3 and COL 1).
id3 is the auto increment.
COL 1 contains 3 types of values A/0/1.

These values follow a strict rule.
After an A can a 0 or 1 follow.
After a 0 can only an A follow.
After a 1 can only a 1 or a 0 follow.

It looks like this:

```
id3    | COL 1
------ | ------ 
  1    |  A
  2    |  1     
  3    |  1     
  4    |  0
  5    |  A
  6    |  0
  7    |  A   
  8    |  1
  9    |  0
 10    |  A
```

What I want is the number of 1s in a row between two A for the entire column stored in a second table (garb). 
The end result should look like this:

```
  Val
  ------
   2
   0
   1
```

My approach so far was to copy only the values which repeat after each other into the new table.
For that I used this code:

```
INSERT INTO garb (ida2)  SELECT id3  FROM cor;

INSERT INTO garb (ida) SELECT Id3 from cor a1 where 0 < (select count(*) from cor a2 where a2.Id3 = a1.Id3 + 1 and a2.`COL 1` = a1.`COL 1`);
```

Now I have the ids from the repeating 1. I also know when a 2 number break is that the next repeat started.

But how do I count and save the number of repeats between each  A?
Or if there is an easier solution would also work.

Thanks in advance,
Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option can be (be careful performance issues):

```sql
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `garb`, `cor`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `garb` (
    ->   `ida` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cor` (
    ->   `id3` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ->   `COL 1` CHAR(1),
    ->   KEY (`COL 1`)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `cor`
    ->   (`COL 1`)
    -> VALUES
    ->   ('A'), ('1'), ('1'), ('0'),
    ->   ('A'), ('0'), ('A'), ('1'),
    ->   ('0'), ('A');
Query OK, 10 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 10  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> INSERT INTO `garb`
    -> SELECT SUM(IF(`cor`.`COL 1` = '1', 1, 0)) `Val`
    -> FROM (
    ->   SELECT
    ->      `cor_out`.`id3` `min`,
    ->      (SELECT `cor_in`.`id3`
    ->       FROM `cor` `cor_in`
    ->       WHERE `cor_in`.`id3` > `cor_out`.`id3` AND
    ->             `cor_in`.`COL 1` = 'A'
    ->       LIMIT 1) `max`
    ->   FROM `cor` `cor_out`
    ->   WHERE `cor_out`.`COL 1` = 'A'
    -> ) `der`
    ->   INNER JOIN `cor` ON `cor`.`id3`
    ->     BETWEEN `der`.`min` AND
    ->             `der`.`max` AND
    ->     `cor`.`COL 1` != 'A'
    -> WHERE `der`.`max` IS NOT NULL
    -> GROUP BY `der`.`min`, `der`.`max`;
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT `ida`
    -> FROM `garb`;
+-----+
| ida |
+-----+
|   2 |
|   0 |
|   1 |
+-----+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/x5iha5bZwHxu6ebKGVhRkS/0).